# Kivy Scale Image Not Working

Tags: python, image, kivy

so i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955821/resizing-an-image-to-variable-fixed-dimensions) that this kivy file should make my image 40x40: but all it changes is the position. How could I change the size? This needs to be in the .kv file.

**code:**

Kivy File

```
#kivy 1.7.2
Root:
    Image:
        source: 'torch.png'
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        height: dp(40)
        width: dp(40)
```

Main Script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass
class RPGApp(App):
    pass
RPGApp().run()
```

Comment: I just tried this based upon the other question. What does the function db even do?? Honestly im new to kivy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you want `dp`, not `db`? This converts from units of density independent pixels, i.e. it should remain the same 'real' size on screens with different pixel densities.

If you just want your image to be 40 pixels square, you can omit the function altogether (i.e. `height: 40` and `width: 40` or just `size: 40, 40`).

This is explained on kivy's [metrics](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html) page.

Comment: still not working. Is it possible to scale the image using the pygame api? my [little image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/38cy7a15jynes7c/torch.png) is still not scaling up, its tiny in the bottom left corner. and if I had a guess its at (40, 40)

Comment: If you want it to scale to larger than the real height of the image, you must also set `allow_stretch: True`. Check the [Image docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html) for more information.

Comment: so how can I change the position now?? (like I said I am new to kivy. It works perfectly, and I dont need it any clearer, but using just 'position: 50, 50' doesnt seem to work.

Comment: The position propery is called `pos`. You should go through the introductory guide and examples (e.g. the pong example) to see this kind of thing.

Comment: okay, i havent looked at those for a while(im actually restarting kivy). I tried position so pos will work, thanks